# Не работает сервер Java EE

Tags: java-ee, java, tomcat, сервер

Здрасте, потратил кучу времени так и не решив вопрос, прошу помочь мне разобраться. В общем ставил я Eclips EE по этим [пунктам](http://www.technerium.ru/tehnologiya-java-servlet/izuchaem-jsp-i-servlets-chast-1-nastroyka-tomcat-7-eclipse-java-7) до 7-го. Все должно быть нормально но друг Eclips выводит сообщение:

> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost
> was unable to start within 45 seconds.
> If the server requires more time, try
> increasing the timeout in the server
> editor.

В консоле пишет:

> січ. 15, 2014 3:06:51 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
> init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat
> Native library which allows optimal
> performance in production environments
> was not found on the
> java.library.path: C:\Program
> Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\syste
> m32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Program
> Files\NVIDIA
> Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program
> Files\AMD
> APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System
> 32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Progr
> am Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
> Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
> ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
> Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows
> Kits\8.0\Windows Performance
> Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
> SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
> Files\ATI
> Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program
> Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program
> Files\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program
> Files\Common Files\Autodesk
> Shared\;E:\javaSE\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse;;.
> січ. 15, 2014 3:06:51 AM
> org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule
> begin WARNING:
> [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
> Setting property 'source' to
> 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test-app'
> did not find a matching property. січ.
> 15, 2014 3:06:52 AM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol
> init INFO: Initializing
> ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"] січ.
> 15, 2014 3:06:52 AM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol
> init INFO: Initializing
> ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] січ.
> 15, 2014 3:06:52 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
> load INFO: Initialization processed in
> 1040 ms січ. 15, 2014 3:06:52 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService
> startInternal INFO: Starting service
> Catalina січ. 15, 2014 3:06:52 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine
> startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet
> Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 січ. 15,
> 2014 3:06:54 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
> startInternal SEVERE: A child
> container failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test-app]]
> at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(Contain
> erBase.java:1128) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(Standard
> Host.java:782) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(Conta
> inerBase.java:1566) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(Conta
> inerBase.java:1556) at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test-app]]
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:154) ... 6 more Caused by:
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException:
> Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(
> Constant.java:131) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(Co
> nstantPool.java:60) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConsta
> ntPool(ClassParser.java:209) at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(Clas
> sParser.java:119) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations
> Stream(ContextConfig.java:2032) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations
> Jar(ContextConfig.java:1923) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations
> Url(ContextConfig.java:1891) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations
> (ContextConfig.java:1877) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextC
> onfig.java:1270) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(Con
> textConfig.java:855) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(Con
> textConfig.java:345) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent
> (LifecycleSupport.java:119) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(Li
> fecycleBase.java:90) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(Stand
> ardContext.java:5161) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) ... 6 more
>
> січ. 15, 2014 3:06:54 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
> startInternal SEVERE: A child
> container failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
> at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(Contain
> erBase.java:1128) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(Standa
> rdEngine.java:302) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(Stand
> ardService.java:443) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(Standa
> rdServer.java:732) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675
> ) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:3
> 22) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45
> 0) Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:154) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(Conta
> inerBase.java:1566) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(Conta
> inerBase.java:1556) at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> A child container failed during start
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(Contain
> erBase.java:1136) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(Standard
> Host.java:782) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) ... 6 more
>
> січ. 15, 2014 3:06:54 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
> start SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardServer[8005]] at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:154) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675
> ) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:3
> 22) at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45
> 0) Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardService[Catalina]] at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:154) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(Standa
> rdServer.java:732) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) ... 7 more Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina]] at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:154) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(Stand
> ardService.java:443) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) ... 9 more Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> A child container failed during start
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(Contain
> erBase.java:1136) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(Standa
> rdEngine.java:302) at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.j
> ava:150) ... 11 more
>
> січ. 15, 2014 3:06:54 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
> start INFO: Server startup in 1874 ms

80 порт не занят(если че). Подумал что где то протупил, установил все заново(даже JDK), та самая проблема. Что это может быть?

Comment: Проблема решилась после того как скачал и установил новую версию Томкат 7.0.50, теперь все работает!

Comment: > Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

это сообщение никакого отношения к томкату не имеет т.к. оно шаблонное и могло быть выведено для любого сервера. оно всего-лишь означает что `eclipse` послал команду веб серверу а тот не ответил вовремя, такое бывает (напр: у вас очень большой проэкт и время старта томката больше времени ожилания выполнения команды, что собственно и произошло у вас).

скорее за все проблема возникла из-за несовместимости старого `tomcat` и `java 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные среды?

Comment: Tomcat 7.0.35 все нормально работает...